# GoogleScript trigger event when cell is clicked, value entered, but the value is the same as the previous value

Tags: javascript, events, onchange

Could you please help me? My issue is the following:

In google script(google sheets), is there a way to trigger an onChange or onEdit or similar event, when a cell is

- not empty
- clicked
- value entered
- but the new value is equal to the old value?

Eg: A1:A1 contains 1234. If i click into the cell, write 1234, no event triggered, but if write any other than 1234 (e.g. 4321), the event triggered. Example code:(this is only attempts):

```
//function onEdit(e){
function onChange(e){

Browser.inputBox("ON CHANGE");
if (e.value == "[object Object]") 
{
    Browser.inputBox("NOT CHANGED");
}else
{
    Browser.inputBox("CHANGED");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `onClick` `onFocus` or `onBlur` events instead when no event is triggered by the `onChange`.

Comment: As I noticed, there is no onClick or the others present in gs, only onEdit or onChange :(

Comment: I looked into the documentation and there doesn't seem to be a direct way to do what you want. 

Your use case is a bit odd though. Why do you want to trigger something if their is no change in the sheet.

Comment: Because i have to make a small script which has the following functionalities:
-when a cell in a given column updated -> write the current time and user to another cell <- this could be done, its ok.
-when a cell in the given column updated, get the previous value add it to the new value and set the cell value to this sum. (and it is a real use-case that a user writes e.g. 10.000 to a cell which contains 10.000 already and should contain 20.000 from now :/